# Select a row and get data (Android Studio SQLlite)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have a table with two columns (`productname` and `answer`).
When I enter a number, the cursor needs to go to that row and get that data.
For example, if I give 5 as a number to `QuestionID`,
the `c1` cursor should go to the 5th cell in column `productname` and
the `c2` cursor should go to the 5th cell in column `answer`.

Please look at the code below...

```java
public void getexactrow(String QuestionID){
    this._QuestionID=QuestionID;

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String colomn1 = "SELECT " +COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME+ " FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";
    String colomn2 = "SELECT " +COLUMN_ANSWER+ " FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";

    Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(colomn1, null);
    Cursor c2 = db.rawQuery(colomn2, null);

    c1.move(Integer.parseInt(_QuestionID));
    c2.move(Integer.parseInt(_QuestionID));

    if (c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null) {
         _SendQuestion = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("productname"));

    }

    if (c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("answer")) != null) {
        _SendAnswer = c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("answer"));

    }
}
```

Comment: this is my string list

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "qulo.db";

    public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "que";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";

    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";

    public static final String COLUMN_ANSWER = "answer";

Comment: what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: when im give 2 to QuestionID. c1 cursor goaes to first row on the second colomn.not the second row of the first coloumn.

thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1):

> Update the code with taking in example below code, using single cursor and removing where clause with 1 as value

```
public void getexactrow(String QuestionID){

SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
String colomn1 = "SELECT " +COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME+ ","+COLUMN_ANSWER+" FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;
Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(colomn1, null);

c1.move(Integer.parseInt(QuestionID));

if (c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null) {
     _SendQuestion = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("productname"));
}

if (c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("answer")) != null) {
    _SendAnswer = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("answer"));

}
```